# Runtime.ImportModuleError - Getting the error on lambda Server when trying to import local util files

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I have included a utils file in my handler.js file. It works fine locally, but when testing the same after deploying it with serverless in lambda, it throws the following error -

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'myModules/utils/bCryptPwd'",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'myModules/utils/bCryptPwd'",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:100:13)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:36:30)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)",
        "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)",
        "    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:829:12)",
        "    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)",
        "    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)"
    ]
}
```

Please Note that the file name I am using is "bCryptPwd". I moved the folder to node_modules and I am using it in my handler.js function as shown below.

```
const {bCryptPwd} = require('myModules/utils/bCryptPwd');
```

I expected the nodejs require to work as expected as it did on local, however it did not. Any help would be appreciated.

Adding package.json. I recently did this initialization as serverless didn't create package.json

```
{
  "name": "lamdaserver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "handler.js",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
},
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: please include your `package.json` file.

Comment: I have added the same.

Answer (score 0):

Without a relative file path node will try to import the module from `node_modules`.

You will want to qualify the path relative to the location fo the file.
Something like `const {bCryptPwd} = require('./myModules/utils/bCryptPwd');`